# PL/SQL- How to run a 3rd party Stored Proc for each SYS_REFCURSOR row and still pass the cursor to 3rd party app (C# WPF) as efficiently as possible

Tags: plsql

Trying to accomplish 2 things, while avoiding any unnecessary overhead:

1. Query multiple tables with Joins to pass SYS_REFCURSOR to a C# WPF for order processing.
2. For each item in that same query result, send to a 3rd party Stored Procedure, of which a workaround is not an option, nor is even viewing the code.  Its function is to update a status of each record.

I can get either to work, but not both.  I realize I may have no choice but to use global temporary table or other option (which is best?)  So the resulting answer may be more of "what path should I choose", as much as "how to do it".

Tried a single SP:  #2 worked, but #1 did not - no error, just returned no results, when there are results.  Then tried an autonomous function:

```
PROCEDURE SP_GET_ORDERS( O_ORDERS SYS_REFCURSOR ) AS
v_ticket_id  NUMBER; -- used for attempt using loop inside this SP
cursor_id    NUMBER; -- same
BEGIN
OPEN O_ORDERS FOR  --(simplified)
  SELECT
        a.TICKET_ID, a.ORDER_NO, a.CURR_STATUS, 
        b.STATUS
  FROM tableA@DBLINK_A a
      JOIN tableB@DBLINK_B b ON a.ORDER_NO = b.ORDER_NO
  WHERE
        a.ORDER_TYPE = 'MINE'
        AND a.CURR_STATUS IN ('OPEN', 'PENDING');
--Above alone will work for #1, of course

--Loop  (When added this will work for #2, but then #1 breaks - does it 'wreck' the sys refcursor ?)
  dbms_sql.define_column(curid,1,v_ticket_id);
  WHILE DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(cursor_id) > 0 LOOP
    DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(cursor_id, 1, v_ticket_id);
    REMOTE_SCHEMA.SP_REMOTE_UPDATE@MY_REMOTE_DBLINK(v_ticket_id);
  END LOOP;

--Attempt #3 (after many searches here and elsewhere) I wrote an autonomous transaction 
--and replaced the loop above with the call to it, passing the sys refcursor:
SP_ASSIGN_STATUS(O_ORDERS);
END SP_GET_ORDERS;

PROCEDURE SP_ASSIGN_STATUS( O_ORDERS IN SYS_REFCURSOR )
IS PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
lv_cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
v_ticket_id  NUMBER;
cursor_id        NUMBER;

BEGIN
  lv_cursor := O_ORDERS;
  cursor_id := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(lv_cursor);
  
  dbms_sql.define_column(cursor_id,1,v_ticket_id); 
  WHILE DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(cursor_id) > 0 LOOP
    DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(cursor_id, 1, v_ticket_id);
    REMOTE_SCHEMA.SP_REMOTE_UPDATE@MY_REMOTE_DBLINK(v_ticket_id);
  END LOOP;
END SP_ASSIGN_STATUS;
```

The autonomous transaction does the same thing as the loop in the original SP-- it runs #2 updates, but does not return any results for #1

Ideally I'd like to use 1 query, retrieve the 1st column (TICKET_ID), pass that to the loop to update the SP/remote table, while preserving the SYS REFCURSOR (that works) to pass same result to the WPF app.

Any suggestions? New to PL/SQL and still grasping at the objects, scope, lifespan, use, etc. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered getting the WPF app to do the call to assign the status? I'm assuming that the purpose is for the status to be updated once the row is sent to the WPF app? Seems better for that app to handle it, especially if it errored whilst processing the row.

Comment: @Boneist - I have.  Trying to reduce any and all back and forth if possible.  I find it surprising that I can't do 2 things with the same SYS REFCURSOR, all in PL/SQL, in one SP.  Can anyone comment on this?  Is it truly not possible, or am I just doing it wrong? If not, another call from WPF app or using temp tables will have to suffice.

Comment: A cursor is simply the set of instructions on how to retrieve a dataset. If you retrieve a row from a cursor, you've already retrieved that row; it can't be retrieved a second time. You either need to store it somewhere (I'm not sure a GTT would be the right thing to use here, since the data in it is session based; probably a collection is best), run the cursor for a second time (which might pull back a different set of data), or change the logic so you don't need to retrieve the same data twice.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that just because you've opened a cursor, it doesn't mean that you have to do anything with the data, so in your case (assuming I've got the process flow correct!), it seems more logical for the app to retrieve a row, update the status if applicable (e.g. "this row is being worked on!"), do the processing of that row, then update the status (e.g. "done!" or "errored!" depending on whether the processing was successful or not), then fetch the next row in the cursor and repeat.

Comment: @Boniest I think your 2nd statement answered my question- "If you retrieve a row from a cursor, you've already retrieved that row; it can't be retrieved a second time.".  In my mind it would still be there -or- in the case of the Pragma autonomous function, I hoped that reassigning the cursor would create a 'new' cursor object, that could then be used.  It seems not- it is using the same cursor object and I cannot reuse it.   Rewrite that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Also- comment on what should I use?  I really just want a variable, list, array, etc-- something as lightweight as possible in PL/SQL to process the '3rd party' SP updates AND still pass a refcursor to WPF.   I can update WPF, if thats the best solution.  (so just return the refcursor, 'do the needful' in WPF, then send another request to Oracle to update the 3rd party SP based on a list or such. It just seems like so much unnecessary processing).

Comment: What would happen in the event you update the rows in PL/SQL but the processing fails in the WPF app? Wouldn't that cause a mismatch? I applaud your desire to minimise the work being done but, given it appears you're doing row-by-row processing in your app, it just doesn't seem logical to apply it here. Your update-the-row-in-the-remote-db is row-by-row, so I don't think you're adding that much overhead by letting the WPF app have the control of the transaction instead of trying to force the db to do all the work, and it'll be easier to control things when processing fails for a single row.

Comment: Very good points to consider.  I'll go that route.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're thinking that a cursor is a set of rows already predefined and fetched into some sort of internal array. It's not; it's a set of instructions on how to fetch the rows at the point the cursor was opened. Once you fetch a row, the cursor moves on to how to fetch the next row, meaning you cannot fetch the previous row again.

Think of it like a bucket of multicoloured balls - if I tell you to hand me the first red ball in the bucket, once I have the ball in my hand, I can't instruct anyone else to get me that exact ball, since it's no longer in the bucket. (It's not a great analogy, as what happens in the db is way more complicated, but hopefully it gets the point across!)

In your case, it seems like you're processing the rows one-by-one (i.e. procedurally rather than set-based), and therefore it makes more sense for the thing that starts the transaction (your app) to handle all the processing for that row, including updating the status of that row, especially since the procedure that updates the row is doing row-by-row processing rather than one big update statement.

It's good that you're trying to think set-based and maximise the work the db does, but it doesn't really seem the best approach here, particularly in the case when there's a failure in the processing of a row - how would the app be able to control the status of that row if it's already been updated by the db code? Much more sensible to let the app set the appropriate status, be that success or failure.